# Next js project. Need to load translations from s3 bucket with react-i18next library but get an error Text content does not match server-rendered HTML

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, react-i18next

I have a project on next js, I need to add loading translations from s3 aws service. I use react-i18next library for translations. My config.

```
    import i18next from 'i18next';
    import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
    import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';
    import ChainedBackend from 'i18next-chained-backend';
    import HttpBackend from 'i18next-http-backend';
    import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
    import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
    import translationsEN from '../../assets/translations/en.json';
    import translationsUA from '../../assets/translations/ua.json';
    
    const resources = {
        en: {
            translation: translationsEN,
        },
        ua: {
            translation: translationsUA,
        },
    };

class LocalizationService {

    constructor() {
        this.fallbackLng = 'en';
    }

    async init() {
        await i18next
            .use(ChainedBackend)
            .use(initReactI18next)
            .use(LanguageDetector)
            .init({
                debug: true,
                // load: 'languageOnly',
                fallbackLng: this.fallbackLng,
                interpolation: {
                    escapeValue: false,
                },
                detection: {
                    order: ['navigator'],
                    caches: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],
                    cookieMinutes: 10000000,
                },
                backend: {
                    backends: [HttpBackend, resourcesToBackend(resources)],
                    backendOptions: [
                        {
                            loadPath:
                                'https://project.s3.amazonaws.com/static/translations/{{lng}}.json',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            });
    }
}
```

in _app.jsx I have the next service declaration

```
(async () => {
    await LocalizationService.init();
})();

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) { ... }
```

But I receive the error **Text content does not match server-rendered HTML**

And I can see that client downloads translations from s3 but a server takes from the local resources. I do not know how to make an app download translations from the s3 without errors.

Comment: I do not mind changing a library to work with translations but It should be compatible with s3.